# Outliner locked me out, layers highlighted green, and many layers are hidden cant unhide

Tags: outliner

I accidently did something to my outliner that I can't find or figure out how to undo.
All of my layer trees are gone except one but all objects are in the 3D viewport. I also can't do anything in my outliner except go into edit mode for the visible layers and toggle their 3 options.
[image]
All layers are highlighted green.. I can't contract the layer trees that are visible and the other layers are there but are invisible.
I know they're there because when I go to object in properties, the drop down menu shows all my layers that are hidden from the outliner.
When I select one of those layers or object I mean, the outliner doesn't show the layer for that object. What does layers highlighted green in outliner mean?
I want control of my outliner back, how do I undo this?
thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There aren't any layers in Outliner, it shows object datablocks present in your scenes (in this case in the parented hierarchy).

Highlighted in green means results of the search:

[image]

Above green highlight shows everything which fits letter "M" in the search (which can be anywhere in the word).

Remove the search keywords and search filter won't be applied anymore.

Aside from that some objects in your scene are set as non-editable (White Arrows to the right from the object datablock name), which means they will be visible but not selectable. You might need to turn them on for further editing.

Comment: OMgosh... I feel so silly... thank you, I didn't remember that I had used the search.. I didn't see it either, on a 4K screen and is easy to miss. Thanks a bunch! You saved me from a lot more stress, thank you